# Can remote powershell start this process?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to start a dogecoin miner process on my machine over SSH. It won't start because it can't connect to the CUDA drivers because SSH doesn't seem to load them for the session. [I asked a question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/778004/trying-to-start-miner-process-from-ssh-but-fails) where somebody mentioned using Powershell to remotely connect and start the process in hopes that it'll start under the right "context" to access the CUDA drivers.

I've always been a little leery about allowing Powershell to run remotely on my machine, especially if it'd be accessible from over the internet. Can Powershell do this and what security concerns might there be for allowing remote Powershell to run?

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect using PowerShell will help you access the CUDA drivers either. I think the core issue is that the remote endpoint is running as a service and is not allocated a desktop on the remote machine. If there's no desktop, there's no GUI; no gui, no CUDA.

Comment: Any workaround for this? My computer is always signed into and displaying on my monitor (which may be off). I've found that for RDP, I can make my RDP session become the main desktop session (i.e. sign out of RDP and have the desktop show back up on the monitor). Could this sort of session management be manipulated to allow me to start a process on a session with a desktop?